# django template code not loading: "TemplateSyntaxError : Invalid block tag on line 19: 'applink'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?"

Tags: python, html, django, templates

I am building a Django app with Django 1.9.4 and Python3.4. I keep getting the error:

```
Error during template rendering

In template /home/enlighter/workspace/ndl-question-papers-search-hub/qp_search_project/templates/base.html, error at line 19
block tag on line 19: 'applink'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

  14      <body>
  15        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  16          <div class="container">
  17            <div class="navbar-header">
  18              <a href="http://ndl.iitkgp.ac.in/" class="navbar-brand"><img src="{% static "images/ndl-logo.png" %}" height="21" /></a>
  19              <a href="{% applink "/" %}" class="navbar-brand">NDL QP</a>
  20            </div>
  21
```

This is my project directory structure:

```
manage.py
qp_search_project
searcher
|--admin.py
|--apps.py
|--forms.py
|--static
   |--css
|--models.py, etc.
templates
|--base.html
|--searcher
   |--index.html
```

The above html code with the `"{% applink "/" %}"` is in base.html and my searcher/index.html is :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}
Search Question Papers
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
blah blah blah
{% endblock %}
```

And the method rendering this `index.html` page in my app's `views.py` is :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .forms import NameForm

applink = "/searcher"

def index(request):
    context_dict = {
        'applink' : applink
    }
    return render(request, 'searcher/index.html', context_dict)
```

I am trying to render 'applink' from context and append `/` to it? In other words, I want to render `'/searcher/'`

Please help!

This Django project code is in the repository:
https://github.com/enlighter/ndl-question-papers-search-hub/tree/master/qp_search_project

Comment: You dont have a templatetag named `applink` are you trying to render `applink` from context and append `/` to it? In other words, do you want to render `'/searcher/'`?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @v1k45 yes exactly that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To render context object, you are supposed to use `{{ applink }}` not `{% applink %}`

In your template:

Replace this:

```
<a href="{% applink "/" %}" class="navbar-brand">NDL QP</a>
```

with this:

```
<a href="{{ applink }}/" class="navbar-brand">NDL QP</a>
```

Read [django-docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/overview/#design-your-templates)